# lowercase title bib latex

Tags: biblatex, titles

Following some suggestions I used:

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{titlecase}{\MakeSentenceCase{#1}}
```

to `SentenceCase` the title.

However, only the name of the conference and not the actual title seems to be affected

```
A. C. Bahnsen, A. Stojanovic, D. Aouada, and B. Ottersten. “Cost sensitive credit card fraud detection using bayes minimum risk”. In: Proceedings - 2013 12th inter- national conference on machine learning and applications 1 (2013), pp. 333–338.
A. C. Bahnsen, A. Stojanovic, D. Aouada, and B. Ottersten. “Cost sensitive credit card fraud detection using bayes minimum risk”. In: Proceedings - 2013 12th Inter- national conference on Machine Learning and applications 1 (2013), pp. 333–338.
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, `{{MYTITLE}}` will prevent any re-casing from happening.